# Missing ASP.NET Core templates in VS Enterprise 15 Preview 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I just installed Preview 5.  I've mainly been doing front-end work for the past year, but I figured I'd start checking out .NET core finally, now that it seems more stable.

I've got an MSDN subscription, so I grabbed the Enterprise Preview 5 download and installed it.

- [Here](http://prntscr.com/d3gshz) are my options for framework version when I go to start a new project.
- [Here](http://prntscr.com/d3gsr6) are my options for new web project.  If I reopen the installer to Manage my installation,
- [here](http://prntscr.com/d3gtmk) are the .NET components I have installed.
- [Here](http://prntscr.com/d3gu0g) are my compilers and build activities.  As far as I can tell, I've got everything I need to have installed in order to use DNC, but it's just not showing up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a `.NET Core` tab under `Visual C#` after I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) although I'm not sure if it's the same for VS 15, I've been using VS 2015 with Update 3.

However it appears that some templates have been published [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5) and maybe this is what you're looking for.

I'm not sure about "it seems more stable" especially that they still didn't move from `project.json` to `.csproj` (scheduled for the end of the year) but good luck and have fun. Be patient, it will get there :).